# How to apply software display calibration while running F.lux?

Tags: windows-7, colors, calibration, f.lux

I got great results from doing software calibration with Color Management in Windows 7, but F.lux resets the profile to its own every second. Is there any other way to calibrate the display that works alongside F.lux? AMD Vision Engine Control doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Powerstrip perhaps? Giving it a try.

Comment: Didn't work by the way.